# Remove Value from JSON array

Tags: json

How do I remove a value from a JSON array? Say I have an array like
`var my_array = [3,6,4,8,11]`
and I want to remove the number 4 from the array. I have tried `delete my_array(4)` but that just removes index 4 and apparently it doesn't delete it, it leaves a `NULL` gap in its place. I simply need to remove the number out of the array entirely. But I don't know at what index that number is positioned so I can't use something like `splice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must find index of what you need first..

```
var my_array = [3,6,4,8,11]
var will_delete = my_array.indexOf(4);
my_array.slice(will_delete,1)
```

Please confusion splice and slice

Splice : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Slice : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Comment: Thanks very much Burak! Thats almost working. Its getting the index just right, but for some reason its not removing the item. Here is what I have:
`var fave_array = JSON.parse(Cookies.get('favorite'))
var will_delete = fave_array.indexOf(fave_id);
fave_array.slice(will_delete,1)
alert(fave_array)`

Comment: Because slice not mutate array, you must assign it to new array var new = foo.slice(x,1)

Comment: Hey - Sorry I thought I had it. I have `var new_fave_array = fave_array.slice(4,1); alert(new_fave_array)` but the result is a empty array. It seems to wipe out all entries in the array. Any ideas?